# using a magic contant class to return file path of calling class

Tags: php, constants

I've been using the following to return filepath and line number of a method

```
echo (__METHOD__) . "() - ln : " . (__LINE__) . "<br />";
```

I'd really like to update this to a class (say comment.php)

```
class comment
{   
    public static function show()
    {
        echo (__METHOD__) . "() - ln : " . (__LINE__) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

that I can call from anywhere in my development

```
if(COMMENT) comment::show();
```

and have it return the filepath of the calling code. I've tried a few variants but I'm missing something. Can you help?

thanks

Comment: do you want to return the filepath or the method name & line number?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) - this can give you the information about the caller that you need.

For example:

```
<?php

class comment
{
    public static function show()
    {
            $trace=debug_backtrace();
            print_r($trace);
    }

    public function test()
    {
         comment::show();
    }

}

$comment=new comment();
$comment->test();
```

Will produce this output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /tmp/test.php
            [line] => 13
            [function] => show
            [class] => comment
            [type] => ::
            [args] => Array()

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /tmp/test.php
            [line] => 19
            [function] => test
            [class] => comment
            [object] => comment Object ()
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array()

        )

)
```

The first element shows the caller details - format this to your liking, and display the whole call stack too if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo __FILE__;
```